# Why can't I use this string unicodeescape in Python (Windows 10)?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

I am using python to open a file.
I am using windows 10 and python.

The problem is though that when I try type the directory for my file I get an underline on the first character (the C) and it says "unicode error 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape". This means I can't run my code, it just breaks.

I am quite experienced with python, but I have never seen this error and I don't even know what a codec or a unicodeescape is.

here is my code

```py
import random
import time
def My_file():
    My_file = open("C:\Users\Azra\Documents\hacker stuff\programmes\python\My_file.txt")
    print("file is loading...")
    for percent in range(1, 100, 1):
        print(percent, end='')
        print("%")
        time.sleep(1)
    return My_file
```

Like I have said it has a red line at the C character, how do I fix this? I think it might be a bug with my IDE (integrated development environment) which is Visual Studio Code. I think it might be broken? Are there other IDEs that I could try and use (windows 10)

Comment: You need to double up the backslashes because Python is trying to interpret them as escape sequences. Otherwise use a raw string.

Comment: P.S. `\U` in particular is the start of a Unicode escape.

Answer (score 2):

Mark has answered my question. Thank you Mark.

The solution is to do this instead

```py
import random
import time
def My_file():
    My_file = open("C:\\Users\\Azra\\Documents\\hacker stuff\\programmes\\python\\My_file.txt")
    print("file is loading...")
    for percent in range(1, 100, 1):
        print(percent, end='')
        print("%")
        time.sleep(1)
    return My_file
```

This is because \U breaks strings and so do lots of other combinations, so you can tell python not to break strings if you put \U and not \U

Comment: Just use `/` in file paths on Windows, it works already since Win2000 or earlier

Comment: @rioV8 yes it works, but it's very confusing to anyone who doesn't know that bit of useless trivia.  And if anybody feels the need to "fix" your filename they're going to run into this problem again.